# Cannot build the bootloader of pyinstaller on solaris 10(i386)

Tags: python

Trying to build the bootloader of pyinstaller by this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271487/distribute-python-application-for-solaris-os-by-using-pyinstaller-gives-me-subpr), but fail

error messages :

```
[37/40] cc_link: build/debug/linux/getpath_1.o build/debug/common/pyi_python_1.o build/debug/common/pyi_global_1.o build/debug/common/pyi_launch_1.o build/debug/common/pyi_pythonlib_1.o build/debug/common/pyi_utils_1.o build/debug/common/pyi_archive_1.o build/debug/common/main_1.o build/debug/common/pyi_path_1.o -> build/debug/run_d
ld: fatal: library -lz: not found
ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to /home/devel3/nwtham/python27/pyinstaller/bootloader/build/debug/run_d
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/devel3/nwtham/python27/pyinstaller/bootloader/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1):
        {task: cc_link getpath_1.o,pyi_python_1.o,pyi_global_1.o,pyi_launch_1.o,pyi_pythonlib_1.o,pyi_utils_1.o,pyi_archive_1.o,main_1.o,pyi_path_1.o -> run_d}
```

I try to install libz1-1.2.8,REV=2013.09.23-SunOS5.10-i386-CSW.pkg.gz from [here](http://mirror.opencsw.org/opencsw/bratislava/i386/5.10/), but it still get the same error messages. I check on the folder /opt/csw/lib and found a hyperlink named "libz.so.1" and change it to "libz.so", but I still got the same error message.

My LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
/opt/csw/lib/python2.7:/opt/csw/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/gcc/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/sfw/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/openwin/lib/:/usr/ucblib:/opt/sybase/lib
```

Maybe I install a wrong package, which package should I install?

Python2.7 and gcc4.9.2 all download from [here](http://mirror.opencsw.org/opencsw/bratislava/i386/5.10/).

edit : 
part of the PATH :

```
/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/csw/gcc4/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/opt/csw/bin
```